# Active Directory password

Tags: active-directory

So the issue is with realmd on ubuntu 14-16 and the renew of a password.
so on my setup clients stores the login locally so if you are out of office you still can login to your client. 
now if you are out of office and have vpn access to the office and your password has been changed, the following scenario occurs. you can still login with the old password because you have it stored locally, but if you reboot you loose the vpn connection, you will be unable to get the new password.

My question is simple how do I call AD for a new password while logged in.
I thought I could be easy with an sssd restart, but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked by restarting sssd ( not sure if it had someting to do with this) and then lock your screen while connected to vpn and then i was able to login with the new password.